# Phonegap Jquery Mobile events not working

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've read a lot of discussions but still don't understand my problem.
All I want is to disable button by click on it. It'a sample app where I want button click/tap events to be working.

Head:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<title>Hello World</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="./jq/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the link to see what data-transition="none" does.</p>
    <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="none">Go to Page Two (no effect added)</a>
</div>

<button id="btn1" class="ui-btn">Button</button>
<button id="btn2" class="ui-btn">Button2</button>    

<div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
</div>
```

srcipt which goes before closing body tag. I've tried to place it inside a head end also:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageone", function () {

    $("#btn2").on("tap", function(e) {
        $('#btn2').button({disabled: true});
    });
});
```

Events are working in the desktop browser, but when I launch emulator  - events don't work all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQM button widget is for `<INPUT>` elements. In that case you can use the **[disable](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable)** method:

```
<input id="btn3" type="button" value="Button3" />

$("#btn3").on("tap", function (e) {
    $('#btn3').button("disable");
});
```

In the case of `<BUTTON>` elements like yours, just use regular jQuery to set the disabled prop of the button:

```
$("#btn2").on("tap", function (e) {
    $('#btn2').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L6pf4hoy/)**